# Restler 3 RC4 and Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, autoload, restler

I was having trouble getting the autoload working with Restler 3 RC4 and Amazon Web Services (AWS).  Arul provided a fix which worked beautifully.

```
$loader = require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->setUseIncludePath(true);
class_alias('Luracast\\Restler\\Restler', 'Restler');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this question as answered I'm placing the answer which is part of the question back here

```
$loader = require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->setUseIncludePath(true);
class_alias('Luracast\\Restler\\Restler', 'Restler');
```